# Toyota HiAce 2010 - How to install cruise control stalk?

Tags: toyota, cruise-control, hiace

Looking for some advice with a HiAce cruise control. My 2010 HiAce D4D (Diesel) doesn't currently have cruise control installed, but I read that it is potentially prewired, and all it takes is installing the stalk?

1. How can I know if it's prewired?
2. If it is prewired, how would I connect the stalk?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Here's pictures of the steering wheel and how the connector looks like.

[image: Toyota HiAce 2010 - Steering wheel]
[image: Toyota HiAce 2010 - Steering wheel with airbag cover removed]
[image: Toyota HiAce 2010 - Steering wheel with airbag cover removed - focus on the electronic connector]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does it have a Diesel engine?

Comment: Do you have any reference for the idea that cruise is already installed but just missing the stalk?  That seems unlikely to me.  The WIRING may be there but I will bet that the stalk as well as the throttle actuator are missing.  That's not to say it could not be added but I also suspect the ECU programming for it is missing too.

Comment: By the way.  USE EXTREME CAUTION with what you are doing there in the steering wheel.  The air bag and its wiring is right there.  You should ALWAYS disconnect the battery and fully discharge the SRS system before disassembling it as you have done.  Serious injury or death is quite possible with an unintended air bag deployment!

Comment: @jwh20. It is highly likely that the wiring harness is all there.  A lot of relatively modern cars have electric throttle pedals, so the throttle actuator will already be there too and diesels don’t usually have a throttle, so it is likely just a matter of adding the switches.

Comment: @HandyHowie yes, you’re right it’s a diesel. I’ll edit the question.

Comment: @jwh20 thanks for the reminder. I had read indeed that the airbag could be dangerous and to always unplug the battery. I thought that since I won’t touch or unplug it it would be safe. But next time I’ll unplug the battery, better safe than extremely sorry. Thanks! 
What is the SRS, could you give me more details, or where to look?